# How to find out TextWriter instance is a Console?

Tags: c#

I have an instance of System.IO.TextWriter. It may be passed in from System.Console.  Any way to find out it is Console without causing exception? I tried this but not compiled:

```
   if (_myWriter as System.Console != null ) // error compiling
```

I guess I have to use type checking instead of boxing?

Comment: actually System.Console is a static instance of system.

Comment: @David Chu: No it's not. System.Console is a class and System is a namespace. Are you thinking of Java and System.console()? (Which is then an instance of Console.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like IsConsoleOut below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Console.Out: {0}", IsConsoleOut(Console.Out));
     Console.WriteLine("Other: {0}", IsConsoleOut(new StreamWriter(Stream.Null)));
     Console.ReadLine();
}

private static bool IsConsoleOut(TextWriter textWriter)
{
     return object.ReferenceEquals(textWriter, Console.Out);
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't fool proof, as someone could create their own TextReader directly around the Console output stream (using Console.OpenStandardOutput() to get the stream), and the above function would fail to identify it, but provided the TextWriter has always come from Console.Out it should work - I think!

Comment: how about this
static bool IsConsoleOutput(TextWriter writer, bool outOrError) {
  return (writer != null) && (object.ReferenceEquals(writer,
      outOrError ? Console.Out : Console.Error);
}

Comment: I would rather just use "if (writer != Console.Error)" in the calling code. Why bother with a method with two parameters when it's so easy to just do the comparison? Note that there's no need for the call to Object.ReferenceEquals as TextWriter doesn't overload the equality operator.

Comment: @Jon: Point taken about inlining rather than a the seperate method, but this was only really meant to be an example with illustrative code rather than something to copy verbatim.
With regard to ReferenceEquals vs. ==, the only real reason to use the former over the latter is one of making the intention of the code clearer - there is no ambiguity with ReferenceEquals. I don't think I pay pay a penalty of any sort for doing it that way round, or do I?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if (_myWriter == Console.Out)
```

but that's no guarantee - it could be a wrapper around `Console.Out`, for example.

Why would you want to treat it differently in this case? It would be nicer to design around this than to special-case console writers, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(_myWriter == System.Console.Out)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you reconsider your use cases. System.Console.Out can be redirected to a file, for instance. Would your code still want to treat it as the console?

Comment: Yes. I just pulled out Console feature from my class. So I would not need to check if the TextWriter is a console.